# Class "App\Http\Controllers\Image" not found in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I installed intervention image using composer.phar require intervention/image .
Adding the `Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class`, in aliases and `Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class`, in 'providers'  in config/app.php.

But still Class `App\Http\Controllers\Image` not found.

If I write use Image; on the top of the controller then this happen : GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation. To solve it I uncommented the extension=gd in the php.ini file. But nothing change.

Pls can you tell me ,where I am wrong.

This is my code :

```
public function Store(Request $req){
   
    //validation
    
    $validation = $req->validate([
        'brand_name' => 'required|unique:brands|min:3',
        'brand_image' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png'
    ]);
  

    //file name and store
    $brand_image = $req->file('brand_image');
    $name_gen = hexdec(uniqid()).".".$brand_image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    Image::make($brand_image)->resize(300,200)->save('image/brand/'.$name_gen);
    $storingToDatabase = 'image/brand/'.$name_gen;

        //Insertion
        $brand = new Brand();
        $brand->brand_name = $req->brand_name;
        $brand->brand_image= $storingToDatabase;
        $brand->created_at = Carbon::now();
        $brand->save();
        return back()->with('success','Image inserted successfully');

    
}
```

Comment: Yeah, `use Image;` or `\Image::` instead of `Image::`, or `new \Image()` instead of `new Image()`, etc etc. That's just a common namespacing issue. As for the `GD` library, did you remember to restart your server after making the change to your `ini` file?

Comment: Yes i restarted my xampp server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just can keep using `Image` in your controller, but by adding at the beginning

```
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
```

That will make use of the Intervention package instead.

Answer (score 0):

check if the column name in the table you want to insert name and image are the same and code it
`modelname::create([ 'column_name' => $image_path`;

in model write.
protected $fillable = ['file'];

Comment: I was facing the same error in my code I solved that with these lines of code. Hope, you shall find the solution.